# How does angular actually trigger the life-cycle hooks?

Tags: angular, lifecycle

in a **component** life-cycle we have different interfaces that track different stages in the component
life-cycle, ex. *OnInit*, *OnChanges*, *OnDestroy*..etc
at the run-time how does angular trigger those methods?

for ex. **ngOnChanges()** is triggered when the **@Input** data is changed
now Angular have this logic ***i'm assuming***
1- whenever angular detect changes in the **@input** data
2- angular check if this component class implements OnChanges
3- if true then trigger **ngOnChanges()**

and there is some logic for each of the *life-cycle hooks*
**is this is the way that angular trigger life-cycle hooks?**

Comment: Did you saw the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! Angular's life cycle hooks are implemented by the **[`@angular/core`](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/39b92f7e546b8bdecc0e08c915d36717358c122b/packages/core)** library [[source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169073/Angular-Interview-Questions#contentdiv)].

To prove this, run an [`angular cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) project and in the (optionally chrome) dev tools, place a line break inside a life cycle hook like so:

[image: Select line break inside life cycle hook]

Refresh the page to catch the breakpoint and thus view the call stack:

[image: Catch breakpoint]

The Angular team obviously writes verbose code, so I don't think I need to explain the logic of the following statement that calls `ngOnInit()`:

```
if ((view.state & ViewState.FirstCheck) && (def.flags & NodeFlags.OnInit)) {
    directive.ngOnInit();
}
```

The nice typescript version of this function can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/39b92f7e546b8bdecc0e08c915d36717358c122b/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L151).

Answer (score 1):

[**Angular.io**](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) documented with a image as below,

[image]

This illustrates the hierarchy of lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 0):

Diagram contains list of all the 8 life-cycle hooks(methods) and the sequence in which they are executed.

Application starts with instantiation of a component or directive by calling its constructor which is followed by the life-cycle hooks.

- Black arrows represent the path followed once on instantiation.
- After the component or directive is loaded if there is any change in input data, path followed is represented by red arrows.
  [image]